# How can I get total virtual-memory in windows server 2008 R2

Tags: powershell

I need use powershell(version>=5.1) to get virtual-memory. What can I do ? Now , i only can used `systeminfo.exe`

Answer (score 3):

Will this give you what you want?

```
((Get-Ciminstance Win32_OperatingSystem).TotalVirtualMemorySize)/1mb
```

The number in the output is the total virt memory size in gb (initial value is in kb, so we divide it by 1mb to convert to gb).